# Vector2i doesn't want to cooperate:D

Tags: c++, sfml

My problem is that in the:

```
if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
    {
        source.y=right;
        source.x++;
    }
```

fragment of my simple code, the `source.y` doesn't want to take the value of 0. What's causing this?
Full code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define CW 64//cell width

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow win(VideoMode(1200,800),"lol");
    win.setFramerateLimit(30);

    Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("char.png");

    Sprite char_;
    char_.setTexture(t);

    enum dir{right,left,idle};
    Vector2i source(1,idle);


while(win.isOpen())
{
    win.clear();

    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
    {
        source.y=right;
        source.x++;
    }
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
    {
        source.y=left;
        source.x++;
    }
    else
    {
        source.y=idle;
    }

    char_.setTextureRect(IntRect(source.x*CW,source.y*CW,CW,CW));


    if(source.x==3 || source.x>3)
    {
        source.x=0;
    }

    cout<<"source.x: "<<source.x<<endl;
    cout<<"source.y: "<<source.y<<endl;

    win.draw(char_);
    win.display();


    system("cls");

}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: _doesn't want to take the value of 0_?

Comment: In the enum, right has the value of 0, left has 1 and idle has 2. left and idle works (as in source.y takes the value) but only right which has the value of 0 doesn't work.@Amadeus

Comment: Aside: `if(source.x==3 || source.x>3)` is the same as `if(source.x >= 3)`

Comment: Have you tried `source.y=0;` to see if the problem is really this?

Comment: oh you're right:D hehe. So what;s going on with the source.y?

Comment: yes i have tried setting source.y=0;

Comment: and it doesn't want to take the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158886/discussion-between-adam-w-and-amadeus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `else` after your first `if`:

```
if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
{
    source.y=right;
    source.x++;
}

if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
{
    source.y=left;
    source.x++;
}
else
{
    source.y=idle;
}
```

Even if <kbd>D</kbd> is pressed, you will end up in the final `else` clause, because it's **not** <kbd>A</kbd>. So `source.y` *will* take the value of `right`, but will immediately be overwritten by the line `source.y=idle;`

What you probably want (check the `else` in front of the second `if`) is:

```
if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
{
    source.y=right;
    source.x++;
}
else if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
{
    source.y=left;
    source.x++;
}
else
{
    source.y=idle;
}
```

Comment: dude (or dudet:D) you are a real life saver. I added the <code>else</code> and it works! And i must say that i looked into my older projects with sfml and everywhere where i have this same type of movement scripting i had the <code>else</code> next to the second <code>if</code>. So honestly this was just an error from me. But anyway thank you for you're help and time, I've learn't why this has to be like this:D